# parsing a large csv file using vb.net without newline ending

Tags: vb.net, substring, split

I was given a file that was created with a java program but does not have LF or endofline ending so I am working with a gigantic string. I tried splitting and then using the TextFieldParser but it seems the file is just too big to deal with. The contents are vital to I need to get this data somehow and then clean it up. Here is what I have tried:

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\Desktop\META3.txt")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    MsgBox(currentField)
                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
```

I think the best way is to take substrings of the text and I wanted to take all values after the 7 occurrences of a comma which is what the file should have per line. Not sure how to do this and it seems like regex maybe the only option. Any ideas appreciated.

```
            line = freader.Readline() 
            Dim ms As Match = Regex.Match(line, "(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),")
            line = ms.Value
```

will this work; does not give expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be guaranteed that the number of columns is always consistent why not add a counter that reads each column and then goes onto the next set. You can then create a new spreadsheet or file with the correct format. If you do an search on here there is a package for .net which allows you to build valid .xls and .xlsx files on the fly. The package is called "simple ooxml". i have used this to create all sorts of spreadsheets where I work. I built a command line app that passes and xml file with parameters and builds this as a fully fledged spreadsheet. Hope the above helps. Any questions let me know.

Comment: When I try and read the fields per row it fails because the first line is so long. How would you suggest I read each column? do you mean just import the file into excel?

Comment: just read it using .net. you loop through each line for each column you increment a counter if that counter equals 7 (or you desired number) reset the column counter and create a brand new row on the fly.